# How can I nest data in Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I would like to created a nested file for firebase database that nests as follows:

```
Category{
      Main{
       Books{
     Literature{
     Name: "American Origin",
     Author: "James Odla"
               }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is the Docs node the items you want to associate with the category? That's a bit unclear as there are not *item* in your structure. Also, please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images and links are not searchable so they may not be of use to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using for example `StreamBuilder` and `ListView.builder()` for getting the categories snapshots if your stream is => `Firestore.instance.collection("categories").snapshots()` you should be able to get the category which is clicked => `snapshot.data.documents[index]` and the items => `snapshot.data.documents[index]['items']`.